# How do I populate null values in one table based on values in another, where the join is based on a substring

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables. Table A contains thousands of Product Names where the Wine Type is null. Table B contains hundreds of Wine Varieties and their corresponding Wine Type.

I need to write a Teradata SQL query that will look for substrings in the Table A Product Name and where this is found in the Table B Variety field, then return the Table B Wine Type - to populate the missing Wine Type data in Table A.

If you look at the first row in Table A you can see an example of what should be in the Table A.Wine Type field. The product Name Brilliant Barossa Shiraz Six contains the substring 'Shiraz'. This substring exists in the Table B Variety field, and I need the code to return the corresponding Table B.Wine Type to the Table A.Wine Type ie, RED-WINE.

I've tried the following just to get a basic join as a starting point, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?

```
sel *
from TABLE_A a
inner join TABLE_B b
on a.product_name like '%' + b.variety + '%'
```

[image: WINE TYPE EXAMPLE]

Comment: Is there any online compiler for teradata? I should test the code.

Comment: Please post sample data as text so others can easily use it.

Comment: concatenation operator in Teradata is ||, not +.  Keep in mind that this will have pretty bad performance, probably.

Comment: Note that as shown you potentially will have multiple matches. For example anything that matches `LIKE '%SHIRAZ MATARO%'` would also match `LIKE '%SHIRAZ%'`. And will there always be a match or do you need an outer join?

Answer (score 1):

If you join on LIKE you will always get a cross join. Additionally you might have a name matching multiple rows in table B and then need more logic to return a single value.

If the data in table B is mostly stable the best and most performant way would be a huge CASE, created using SQL, basically like this:

```
select 'when product_name like ''%' || variety || '%'' then ''' || wine_type || ''''
from tableB
```

Based on this you can also prioritize matches.

I've done similar matching with  100KB nested CASEs performing well. For stable data best case is a SQL-UDF automatically created whenever there's a change in data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @dnoeth. Cross Join was the thing I couldn't remember!! The following works a treat now. Just need to tidy it up if the product is a mixed White and Red case of wine. But that is relatively easily done.

Thanks everyone.

```
sel product_name
,case when instr(upper(product_name),variety,1,1) > 0 then wine_type else null end as wine_type

from

(
sel a.product_name, b.variety, b.wine_type
from TABLE_A a
cross join TABLE_B b
) a

where case when instr(upper(product_name),variety,1,1) > 0 then wine_type else null end is not null
```